Could pragmatism be a useful heuristic for "theory choice" between competing religious worldviews (or none at all)?
I asked this question before: How can theoretical disagreements between competing religious worldviews or "theories" be settled?. I ended up accepting this answer. However, I'd like to bring to your attention part of the interaction we had in the comments:

@mudskipper Then how do you propose that we should go about gaining accurate knowledge about the world? How should we judge and compare the accuracy/plausibility of two competing worldviews (religious or otherwise)? – user80226


@user80226 Engineering: use what works best for the particular problem you are trying to solve. Avoid dissent by doing it by yourself. – Scott Rowe


@user80226 - I agree with Scott Rowe's approach. In practice being practical and pragmatic is enough to keep going. In science (and politics and law) there are accepted protocols to try to keep the outliers in check. The essence of science is not knowledge but research. Knowledge is constantly being challenged and changing. – mudskipper


@mudskipper But how would you apply pragmatism to competing religions? Can pragmatism ever favor one particular religious worldview over another? Perhaps it is more pragmatic to remain agnostic? Is living life under the assumption that there is no God even more pragmatic? Methodological naturalism operates in that way. - user80226


@user80226 I often ask myself if my views are helping me. Where they become unquestioned assumptions, or even assumptions I hold unconsciously, then I can make mistakes. Worldviews are just larger assumptions. I make lots of mistakes, so I don't put much faith in my understanding. It leaves me with little way to have faith in anyone or anything else. It's all just judgment calls and bets I am willing to be wrong making. The only certainty I have, I cannot put in words. – Scott Rowe

Through this question, I’d like to explore the plausibility of using pragmatism to assess which religious worldview, among various candidates (presumably pre-selected based on other criteria), may be most plausible—or whether, instead, a non-religious worldview (such as philosophical naturalism or similar metaphysical perspectives) might hold that position.
How might pragmatism support the selection of one particular religious worldview over others, or even over the absence of any religious worldview?

Definition of Pragmatism
From IEP:

Pragmatism
Pragmatism is a philosophical movement that includes those who claim that an ideology or proposition is true if it works satisfactorily, that the meaning of a proposition is to be found in the practical consequences of accepting it, and that unpractical ideas are to be rejected. Pragmatism originated in the United States during the latter quarter of the nineteenth century. Although it has significantly influenced non-philosophers—notably in the fields of law, education, politics, sociology, psychology, and literary criticism—this article deals with it only as a movement within philosophy.


Pragmatism and religion and see William James’s Will to Believe Argument.

There is nothing, pragmatic or otherwise, to be learned about the world from a religious point of view. The only observable and testable benefits are psychological. And all testable claims (such as prayer tests) have failed. As mentioned in your post, methodological naturalism works as a worldview because it is pragmatic: god is not needed as Laplace famously claimed. But methodological naturalism is not merely a custom. We do not use it purely through pragmatism. It’s the result of hundreds of years of investigation finding out that god, and religion, were never used to explain anything.

According to Peirce, it is only the meaning that is to be found in the practical consequences, not the truth, and he heavily criticized "the truth is what works". And even that quip's author, James, had the following to say on 'pragmatism' in choosing a religion in connection with Pascal's wager:"We feel that a faith in masses and holy water adopted wilfully after such a mechanical calculation would lack the inner soul of faith's reality... in the place of the Deity we should probably take particular pleasure in cutting off believers of this pattern from their infinite reward."

I have to learn to make fewer comments.

It should also not go without note: what "works" depends heavily on what goal you are trying to achieve, which is something that pragmatism won't help you figure out

@DarkMalthorp perhaps a good question would be: How should we determine our goals?

@ScottRowe Indeed! If you ask no other philosophical question, you should ask that one! And right now my goal is this: get some sleep  g'night and thanks for some good discussion today.

@MauroALLEGRANZA "pragmatism represents an intellectual stance that has relinquished the canons of strict and consistent rationality and that is engaged is an irresponsible, yet also unavoidable flirtation with relativism." Yikes!

If of such interaction you seek, the chat function would be appropriate

In a global multi-religion setting, faith prevents any religion from admitting they are wrong regardless of the proof or reasoning of a pragmatist.

I was thinking that if choosing goals comes before seeing what works, then choosing desires comes before choosing goals. The problem then, is that desires are quite disconnected from the world, and are not a good basis for making plans. Part of the "do what works" idea is that it wraps a feedback loop around the entire process, so it helps adjust goals and desires too. It is a total strategy.

Since I was quoted in the Question, I am allowed to give an Answer. I'm not sure if my offered idea is actually Pragmatism, or a kind of Stoicism or what, and it doesn't matter to me. I was trying to urge a way of seeing this kind of thing that is a divestment of views and positions, not yet another position. At some stage we hit bedrock and there are no further arguments possible. We then must choose what seems best. That's it, live or die by it but "that's all the farther." I said:

It's all just judgment calls and bets I am willing to be wrong making.

One famous philosopher or scientist used the phrase, "A bet on truth alone." It arrives from within, not from anyone else but yourself. Even if you accept an argument someone else made, it is still your own accession to it, which even God nor the Devil can compel from you. So, man up, say your piece, and take the consequences. Win or fail, no one can rescue you from yourself.

Maybe I should have said "gird up your loins" instead of man up... "Who is this who darkeneth counsel by words without knowledge?" Thomas Merton wrote about The Sign of Jonas, I really liked the Epilogue...

This is the story of Huckleberry Finn, who decides to help the fugitive slave Jim, knowing that it's illegal and may land him in hell, ultimately. "All right then, I'll go to hell." (https://rachelheldevans.com/blog/huck-finn-hell) Perhaps "concretism" is a better word than "pragmatism".

A 'belief' is sometimes pictured as if it was a mental 'state', a picture in the mind, like a old photograph found in a drawer. And comparing beliefs would then presumably be like comparing two drawings or two blurry photographs or a possible-drawing-possible-photograph to another one and deciding... what exactly? Which one resembles "the real thing", the depicted scene, better? Or perhaps, which one is "just a fanciful drawing" and which (if any) is a real photograph of the real thing, "things as they are"?

They said, 'You have a blue guitar,
You do not play things as they are.'
The man replied, 'Things as they are
Are changed upon the blue guitar.'

And how would we decide this? How can we decide which of two pictures resembles 'the real thing" better if we only have those pictures at hand?
But what do we actually want to know? What is the immediate need? Perhaps we only want to know the color of a depicted guitar. A toddler's crude, simple crayon drawing may then be more useful (and "true") than a drawer full of sharp black-and-white photographs. But still, how would we know without yet having another authoritative source at hand?
Picturing beliefs as simple, inert pictures to be inspected and examined by us immediately leads to the problem that - if we only have those pictures, first of all, we don't know in what respects we'd want to compare them, and even if we did decide on this, there is no way to come to any final, conclusive answer since we need either an authoritative picture or a standard. With actual pictures, this standard would be "look with your own eyes". But the mind doesn't have an extra set of eyes with which to verify its beliefs. -- It can only imagine more pictures.

And the color, the overcast blue
Of the air, in which the blue guitar
Is a form, described but difficult,
And I am merely a shadow hunched
Above the arrowy, still strings,
The maker of a thing yet to be made;

Alexander Bain, often quoted by Charles Pierce, critizes the above view of beliefs. He defines belief as "that upon a which a man is prepared to act". In other words, belief is any information one may have that can (and will) control and guide one's actions. This is the core axiom, if you will, of pragmatism: beliefs and actions are inseparable. If we sever the link between belief and action, both become inscrutable and meaningless.
In his Lectures on Pragmatism, Pierce gave the following definition:

Pragmatism is the principle that every theoretical judgement expressible in a sentence in the indicative mood is a confused form of thought whose only meaning, if it has any, lies in its tendency to enforce a corresponding practical maxim expressible as a conditional sentence having its apodosis in the imperative mood. (Lecture V)

He also defined it as

...pragmatism is the doctrine that every conception is a conception of conceivable practical effects. (Lecture VII)

Rather than seeing this as yet another metaphysical doctrine, it's more in the spirit of pragmatism to see this as a practical maxim, a working hypothesis - if you will --, an ongoing project or a (normative) rule of thumb: The truth of any proposition or opinion is to be tested by looking at the practical, observable effects that holding this opinion has.
As to religious views this maxim (or axiom) becomes: Does this or that view, this or that belief, have any actual effect in my life? Does it matter to me? Are the core values of this belief manifested in my actions? -- This is on a purely personal level. I think it makes sense to say that we discover what someone's core values are, not just by what they say, but really by what they do and how they do what they do. As Confucius said:

「始吾於人也，聽其言而信其行；今吾於人也，聽其言而觀其行。
In the beginning, my attitude towards others was "Listen to their words and trust in their actions". Now my attitude is "Listen to their words and observe their actions". (Lunyü 6:10)

Likewise, we feel sympathetic to someone's religion or their values, because we come to admire the person and the actions of that person. In biblical terms

Ye shall know them by their fruits. Do men gather grapes of thorns, or figs of thistles? (Matthew 7:16)


As to other people's religious, a-religious, anti-religious beliefs, I'm generally not interested in any purely cognitive truth value; I also don't know what it would mean to attribute "truth" to an all-encompassing, or grounding view, whether it is a religious one or a "worldview". I'm not aware of having any particular "worldview" myself; when forced to pigeon hole myself into those categories I might say that I'm an atheist, but this mainly is a negative term indicating: I'm not part of this or that traditional group. I'm a pragmatist in sofar that I don't really care about what someone else believes if I cannot see which effects their views have in their lifes or in the life of others (including mine). In sofar as I cannot see this, those propositions or opinions don't have much meaning to me. However, this also implies that I do care a lot when their faith, their beliefs do have noticeable effects in other's lifes.
The point I care about is the conflict point. This is the point were multiple religions, or theists versus atheists, make conflicting claims that concern (i.e. effect) all our lives. At that point, I believe, we need to carefully consider who "we" are and what the limits of cooperation and compromise are. In modern pluralist, non-authoritarian societies we have rejected state religion. We accept that the state should not meddle in religious matters (should not establish a religion or favor one above others) and should also not prohibit free religious expression (assuming this doesn't infringe upon the rights and dignity of others).
The separation of church and state(s) originally was itself a compromise, a pragmatic compromise (every compromise is pragmatic!) that various European nations and radical religious movements agreed upon after decades of intense, bloody religious warfare. From a standpoint of religious, absolute Truth, this compromise may never be completely acceptable -- since the Truth is not up for sale or for negotiation --, and in fact, we can see that it is constantly being challenged by religious fundamentalists and sectarians, who apparently try to find every possible loophole in the laws to nibble away at this separation. But for a pragmatist, the question is: What matters more -- the Truth, the eternal salvation of our souls (or however you want to formulate the religious meaning of life), or actual social peace with our neighbors? If there are conflicting opinions, should they be tolerated or eliminated?

Here is the bread of time to come,
Here is its actual stone. The bread
Will be our bread, the stone will be
Our bed and we shall sleep by night.
We shall forget by day, except
The moments when we choose to play
The imagined pine, the imagined jay.


Quoted verses are from The Man With the Blue Guitar by Wallace Stevens.

Very nice  But long. I'll have to spend more time studying this

It's difficult yo be succinct. @ScottRowe seems to have mastered that art, I have not :)

Blaise Pascal wrote a 100 page letter. And ended with the apology: Kindly forgive me the length of this letter. I've not had the time to shorten it

If objective pragmatism made it possible to find the one true religion, there would only be one religion. A similar yet more consistent approach is Religious Diversity / pluralism: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/religious-pluralism/. This defined here https://www.researchgate.net/publication/330958955_Theology_of_Religion_Pluralism_Inclusivism_Exclusivism as

Pluralism is basically the belief that the world religions are                   true and equally valid in their communication of the truth                   about God, the world, and salvation

Note that "equally true" would not be possible to be 100% true for all, as they are contradicting each other
So that stance rather is like: Surely there is more to life than materialism, many prophets and the like have noticed that much, yet the details of this or that religion are just creative decorum, that has no stronger claim to truth than those details of any other religion.
From that a "believer" can cherry pick whatever they like or not like from any religion, cult, or esoteric writing, and some will mish-mash this also with non religious superstitions like conspiracy theories, homeopathy, numerology...
From that basis, one could pick those practices which work best (for oneself), the way people pick the diet that works best for their lifestyle to lose weight, and in that way a pragmatic subjective choice is possible.
So in practice this could look like: I was not getting along well with my parents, but the teachings of Buddha helped me with that, and I had trouble with falling asleep, but the teachings of the Dalai Lama helped me, and I was so scared of death, but the Orthodox Christian teachings gave me solace, I had trouble climbing up ladders, but my guru is currently teaching me to levitate and we already reached the stage where I am on tiptoes, ...
Philosophically that is a very very subdued theory that merely claims a truth value to some arbitrary intersection of religion without clinging to any detail, rejecting exclusivism and cultist pride.
It's not generally less harmful than other cultist delusions, as one may pick also any intolerant aspect from any cult or superstition, but it satisfies subjective pragmatism.
Objective pragmatism is closest to Agnosticism, accepting that no method or scripture of any cult or religion has any better proven practical effect than similar secular placebo technique, thus rejecting them all alike and sticking with what has proven effects: materialistic science. Naturalism can thus also been seen as a result of objective pragmatism.

When people say "pragmatism," they almost always mean what will "work" in the sense of the here-and-now; such as, what will bring health, wealth, and material prosperity in this life, as prime examples.  But the fatal flaw in using this to choose a worldview is this: In one pre-emptive swipe, it pushes off the table of consideration anything valuing the unseen over the seen, the eternal over the temporal.  But that itself is, in a very real sense, a worldview choice, yet before even beginning to look at worldviews specifically.
So in other words, it would certainly eliminate biblical Christianity from consideration a priori.  Not only does Jesus Christ never use such pragmatism in this life as a reason to follow Him, but He actually says quite the opposite; for example (John 12:24-25):

Verily, verily, I say unto you, Except a corn of wheat fall into the ground and die, it abideth alone: but if it die, it bringeth forth much fruit.  He that loveth his life shall lose it; and he that hateth his life in this world shall keep it unto life eternal.

I.e., Jesus is saying that our current life is like a single corn of wheat; but let it die and be buried, and it will grow back a hundredfold.  Eternity is a long time; but every day in it will be just as real and important as "today" is important to us now.  Eternity will come soon enough (though perhaps not as soon as we Christians would like!); and so our eternal state is what we ought to be consumed with.  I read one Christian quote something like, "Don't drive your tent stakes in too deep, because we break camp in the morning."
Paul also argues that the Christian faith is vain if there is no resurrection (I Corinthians 15):

If in this life only we have hope in Christ, we are of all men most miserable.
. . .
Else what shall they do which are baptized for the dead, if the dead rise not at all? why are they then baptized for the dead?  And why stand we in jeopardy every hour?  I protest by your rejoicing which I have in Christ Jesus our Lord, I die daily.  If after the manner of men I have fought with beasts at Ephesus, what advantageth it me, if the dead rise not? let us eat and drink; for to morrow we die.  Be not deceived: evil communications corrupt good manners.

And here's another promise of God which is precisely the opposite of pragmatism in the here-and-now sense (II Corinthians 4:17-18):

For our light affliction, which is but for a moment, worketh for us a far more exceeding and eternal weight of glory while we look not at the things which are seen, but at the things which are not seen: for the things which are seen are temporal; but the things which are not seen are eternal.

Thus, I'd strongly argue that pragmatism is not a valid means of choosing a worldview, for the reason that it is actually itself a very real worldview choice, and a priori.

Interesting. So as a Christian you seem to be of the type that places all of their bets on afterlife rewards. There are, however, branches of Christianity that are open to unlocking access to the supernatural in this life, but that's controversial, as there are plenty of in-house debates about that. William James's will to believe argument entertains the possibility of unlocking conditional access to "restricted propositions" in this life, although in the context of mysticism in other religions.

@user80226 Yeah, and there are also a lot of TV preachers who promise "health and wealth" in this life, but I'd say it's very clearly unbiblical, and often, they've been the sorts to live lavishly off the "nickels and dimes" of poor and gullible Christians, unfortunately.  (And Jesus Himself warned of such.)  I do believe in rich spiritual blessings here-and-now, which to me, are worth more than all the world, but I doubt I could convince others that it's a good "pragmatic" choice in their meaning, esp. in places where being a Christian can cost you your head, for instance.

Sure, I wasn't referring to the "prosperity gospel", which is probably what you had in  mind. I was rather referring to the controversy surrounding the cessationism vs continuationism debate in Christianity, or traditions like Christian mysticism which are not widely accepted and can be controversial as well.

@user80226 Ah, yes, those are interesting discussions. I do firmly believe in internal, personal experiences of God like peace and specific guidance in answer to prayer.  I'm also somewhere in the middle on cessationism....I think most cited examples aren't actually miracles (e.g., "speaking in tongues" being chaotic or just repetitive), but I also don't personally rule out the possibility, and I do believe God chooses to divinely heal sometimes for instance.

And, of course, excepting the prosperity gospelizers, even the most radical of charismatics still put their bets mainly in the hereafter. There's a reason why the heroes of the Christian faith (including Christ himself) are those who literally faced torture and death rather than give up the faith.

@DarkMalthorp There are people who faced death to give the people they love a better chance at a good life. I met one the other day, he'd been at both the Normandy and Okinawa landings. Maybe people like that should be our exemplars?

Christian pragmatism: Matthew 7:16 "Ye shall know them by their fruits. Do men gather grapes of thorns, or figs of thistles?"

Well yes, you may approach religious questions with pragmatism, asking which stance would be useful. The weak spot here is "useful". In the end, everything we do we do because it is "useful" to us. But "useful" is not necessarily materially useful. Giving to charity, thus reducing our material well-being, may be useful to us because it makes us feel that we are good people. Living the life of an ascetic may be useful to individuals thus inclined because it helps them achieve purity or enlightenment, which they desire.
In the same way, some individuals have strong spiritual, possibly religious feelings. Acting upon them, usually in community with like-minded peers who share similar ideas about deities and how to worship them, is eminently useful to individuals thus inclined. Some people become so miserable when they cannot live their faith that they feel compelled to leave their home, family, friends, possessions and country. They go on perilous journeys across entire oceans to found new countries with constitutions that guarantee the right to worship any way one likes.
Some people are even ready to die for their faith. They could not live without it; death is the better, more "useful" choice for them than a life without faith.

Spinoza: "Only free men are thoroughly useful one to another, and associated among themselves by the closest necessity of friendship." ( Ethics, 4.71) " It is before all things useful to men to associate their ways of life, to bind themselves together with such bonds as they think most fitted to gather them all into unity, and generally to do whatsoever serves to strengthen friendship." (P4-Appendix 12)

@ScottRowe Simplicity should not be the main motivation for education ;-). Nor, in my opinion, should be utility.

@Scott Some people pay for things that are useful, some people pay for things that are beautiful or help the poor. As I said, that may be "useful" to them, and also "benefit" society. Generally I would contend that beyond a certain point (which the Western societies have far surpassed) a richer society is not necessarily a better society, and that an education that aims at making individuals and thus the societies they are part of richer does not make these individuals better people. Most societies acknowledge this and incorporate non-utilitarian subjects in their curricula.

@ScottRowe Ethics or religion is a compulsive subject in Germany.

@ScottRowe Both are concerned with how to live together; it's a bit like reading regular script, or Braille if you are blind (cannot see God).

We rarely ever believe in a theory purely due to pragmatism. When it seems that we do, we are preferring the theory because it makes fewer assumptions as per Occam's Razor. And there's plenty of justifications for believing in more parsimonious theories apart from purely practical or aesthetic reasons.
As an example, methodological naturalism in your post is taken as a view that is believed due to pragmatism. But in reality, it is because it makes fewer assumptions than religious theories. Within both a naturalistic and religious worldview, the natural world exists. The religious worldview posits more. And none of these posits have been successfully demonstrated to explain anything.
As such, what seems "practical" is the result of adopting fewer assumptions. Why posit more than what is needed to explain data?

On the contrary, in terms of brute facts, monotheists have the decisive advantage under Occam's razor: they assert only a single brute fact, i.e. the existence of God, from which the explanation of the universe conscienceness, morality, beauty, meaning etc. all may be derived. A naturalist worldview requires inserting new assumptions (brute facts) to explain each of those things, usually more than one.

As an analogy: if you hear a knock on your door, it would be simplest to assume that the door spontaneously made the sound, if you measure simplicity by the number of things postulated to exist, than to suppose there's someone outside knocking. If the door made the sound spontaneously, there would be no need to postulate the existence of a knocker. Can you spot the problem with this reasoning?

@DarkMalthorp bad analogy. We already know humans exist so positing their existence isn’t anything new. We’ve also directly observed humans knocking on doors. The same doesn’t apply to god.

My point is that it's rather silly to think that the simplest worldview is the one that postulated the smallest number of things (or types of things, for that matter) that exist. I don't see how such a principle can defend itself from collapsing into solipsism. Why do you need to postulate the existence of anything at all beyond your own mind?

@DarkMalthorp Under solipsism, there is no explanation for why you, rather than the other agents you see, are the only ones to possess a mind. Under “non” solipsism, this explanation is already covered by the fact that minds are emergent from the brain which is created by the same physical process that creates other brains. As such, solipsism even if it posits less entities explains less than non solipsism. Occam’s razor only applies if the explanatory power of theories are the same

What other agents?

The other humans that you see in your experience even if they have no mind. The fact that they behave exactly like you but don’t possess a mind has no explanation under solipsism.

I've never met someone who behaves exactly like me. If you have, I'd be quite shocked! In any case, the explanatory power of monotheism is actually far greater than naturalism, as monotheists in one fell swoop can explain the existence of the universe, of morality, and of aesthetics, while naturalists assert the first without explanation and struggle to even get to the other two.

@DarkMalthorp Saying that “god did X” isn’t any more of an explanation of X than “a flying invisible dinosaur did X”. It is not even be better than having no explanation. Without a) prior knowledge of god existing and b) how He does things, these are just words, so where exactly is the explanatory power you are referring to?

If you think about it, every explanation is just words.
